# VimL: Correct use of `call()`? I keep getting error

Tags: vim

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using the following:

```
let g:usefulstatusline_normal=call(exe, ['hi StatusLine'], {})
```

And I get:

```
E15: Invalid expression: call(exe, ['hi StatusLine'], {})
```

What am I doing wrong? It's probably something obvious, I know.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the current colorscheme's statusline's colors and stuff and containing it in a variable. So that I can re-use it later.

Any help is appreciated, also, any tips on how to achieve this in a better way would also be appreciated.

If you want the full code then visit this file: https://github.com/Greduan/vim-usefulstatusline/blob/master/autoload/usefulstatusline_colorize.vim

For now ignore the top part, it's there just for test purposes. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you want the output of the `:highlight command`.  Unlike a function in vim, which returns a value that can be assigned to something on the left hand side of an expression, this command echos its output.  In cases like this, you need to momentarily redirect output into a variable and then restore normal output, like this:

```
redir => g:usefulstatusline_normal
silent! exec 'hi StatusLine'
redir END
```

Note the possible values that the `:highlight` command can output are either an error for a nonexistent highlight group on a single line, or a newline and then the output, so you'll need to do a little more work than just the example above:

```
" Returns: hl group value or '' on nonexistent highlight group
" Usage: let foo = GetHL('StatusLine')
function! GetHL(grp)
  redir => hlOutput
  silent! exec 'hi '.a:grp
  redir END
  let hlVal = matchstr(hlOutput, '\v%(\nStatusLine\s+xxx\s+)@<=.*')
  return hlVal
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. :) I'll try this out later when I get to this. And compare it with Ingo's solution, if he gives me one that returs all the values. :)

Answer (score 4):

Note that for querying the attributes of a highlight group, you do not need to parse the output of the `:hi` command (this should only be done as a last resort, anyway). You can do this with the combination of `hlID()` and `synIDattr()` functions:

```
:echo synIDattr(synIDtrans(hlID('StatusLine')), 'bg')
```

Comment: @cptstubing06: Thanks for your comment; I wanted to keep the answer simple, but I added your feedback, since it's more correct.

Comment: Thanks for that info, @Ingo.  I had been reading `:he synIDattr()`, but `hlID()` was the missing piece to that puzzle.  The canonical version should probably be `synIDattr(synIDtrans(hlID('StatusLine')), 'fg')`.  But even so, one must still wrap this in a bit of logic for the current {mode} and then call it something like 10-14 times to check all possible attributes?  Why do you say `redir` of `:hi` is a last resort?

Comment: `:redir` cannot be nested, it's inefficient and probably slower, and the exact format to be parsed may depend on locale and Vim version.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Thanks for sharing this solution. :) Although I was aware of it because of a previous question I had. The only problem with it is that I want all the values, not only the background. So I need to query once for each value, see what I mean? What would be a way around this?

Comment: I would still prefer querying once for each value over parsing. But the whole idea of querying is unusual. If you want the user to be able to customize the statusline color for each mode, `:hi def ...` default colors for each mode, and let the user override (parts) with `:hi ...`.

Comment: I agree with @Ingo, fwiw, that you're better off defining a default set of highlight groups and letting the user override them (or have variables the user can set to override what highlight groups get used).  It's always better to empower your users rather than try to make personalization choices for them.

Comment: @cptstubing06 That's actually what I'm trying to achieve. :) For normal mode I plan to keep the original statusline colors. However I can't if I don't store it's value somewhere. :) That said, I'm still not decided on what the best way to colorize the statusline would be. Could it be possible you fork my project and figure out a way. :)

Comment: @IngoKarkat Same thing I said to cptstubing06. :) However, for you to be able to contribute: https://github.com/Greduan/vim-usefulstatusline

Comment: @Eduan you shouldn't have to store its value anywhere -- if the user has specified his own highlighting, you use it... If not, use your default.  You don't need to stick to vim's own StatusLine and StatusLineNC highlight groups -- define your own new group name for this and test if it exists (i.e. has been user-defined) before you clobber it with your own default.

Comment: @cptstubing06 OK, I'll do that then. :) Thank you for all your help. :)